# Мошка та гнус - синоніми?

Tags: синоніми

СУМ-20

> [ГНУС](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=168502&page=648)  у, ч., збірн. Дрібні комахи-кровососи, що літають у великій
> кількості; мошва. *Тонесеньке дзижчання звичайно починалось зокола, а
> потім залазило всередину і несподівано пекло болючим уколом. Гнус їв
> поїдом* (І. Багряний).

СУМ-11

> [МОШКА](http://sum.in.ua/s/moshka) и, жін. Дрібна двокрила комаха, схожа на мушку. *А вона
> [птиця] наловить мошок, — Плиг на гілочку рясну* (Дмитро Білоус, Пташ.
> голоси, 1956, 5).
>
> [МОШВА](http://sum.in.ua/s/moshva) и, жін., збірн. Те саме, що мошка. *Дуже мошва диму боїться!*
> (Остап Вишня, I, 1956, 329).

[Із Словника синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0)

> **МОШКА́** *збірн.* (дрібні двокрилі комахи), **МОШВА́**, **МОШКАРА́**
> *розм.*, **МУШВА́** *розм.* *Дзижчить мошка над скошеними травами* (Г. Хоткевич); *Над головою роєм вилася мошва та комарі* (Ю. Збанацький);
> *Який чудесний танок затіяла над пеньком мошкара!* (О. Копиленко); *У
> скісному промені сонця грає роєм мушва* (М. Коцюбинський).

Отже, якщо ***гнус*** і ***мошва*** те саме, чи можемо вважати всі три значення повними синонімами?

Comment: Мені здається що це питання більш ентомологічне ніж лінгвістичне.
вікі https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8 пише:
Мошки (Simuliidae) — родина двокрилих комах, самки імаго яких здебільшого є компонентом комплексу гнуса.

Answer (score 1):

Гдаю, що гнус - це поняття ширше ніж "мошки". Дивимося [Вікіпедію](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%81):

> Видовий склад та чисельність залежить від ландшафтно-географічних та
>   кліматичних умов. До складу гнусу відносяться комарі, мошки, мокреці,
>   ґедзі, а також ряд кровососучих мух (осіння жигалка, коров'яча жигалка
>   і ін.), на півдні — москіти. Протягом сезону спостерігається зміна
>   переважаючих груп і видів кровососів. У широколистяних лісах Далекого
>   Сходу першими починають нападати мокреці, потім до них приєднуються
>   комарі, а потім ґедзі; до середини літа мокреці зникають, але
>   збільшується чисельність комарів родів Culex і Anopheles, а масові
>   види ґедзів поступово змінюють одне одного. Найбільш інтенсивно гнус
>   нападає у порівняно теплу, тиху (без вітру) погоду. Деякі види комарів
>   та мокреців, мошки, ґедзі нападають вдень. Інші види комарів та
>   мокреців, москіти — у передвечірні сутінки або вночі.

І саме визначення гнусу - збірна назва кровососучих двокрилих комах.

А [мошки](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8) - **це родина двокрилих комах**, так само як і [комарі](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%96), [ґедзі](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D2%90%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B7%D1%96) тощо.
Тобто гнус - це багато двокрилих комах, які сосуть кров. І сюди входять і мошки, і комарі, і москіти...